# Wordpress Menu Hover CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on the following site and cannot figure out how to make the menu items background a different color on hover: http://tinyurl.com/q87z34o

I'm using the following CSS and it is not working:

```
.menu-dropdown a.level1 > span, 
.menu-dropdown span.level1 > span:hover {color:#000;}
```

I'ms sure that I'm missing some small, but it's alluding me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: provide the html in the question

Comment: Why a tinyurl and not a regular url? And why not having the code directly in the post? It makes the question look fishy

Comment: As i can see your site hover is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.menu-dropdown a.level1 > span:hover, 
.menu-dropdown span.level1 > span:hover {color:#000;}
```

Adding :hover to both spans did the trick.